# Return specific row from a result set using PHP SQLSRV

Tags: php, arrays, sqlsrv

I have a Stored Procedure that returns two columns of data in the following format that is going to be used for a series of charts;

```
Minutes, [6,15,44,12,15,14,9,5,4,11]
Hours, [41,5,28,7,5,4,19,8,25,6]
Weeks, [1,1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,1]
```

I can return all of these values above on the screen using;

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $sql, $params) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)) ;

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
  echo $row[0].", ".$row[1]."<br />";
}
```

And I can set Minutes, Hours and weeks into variables using;

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch($result, SQLSRV_SCROLL_FIRST);  
$v1 = sqlsrv_get_field( $result, 0);  
$row = sqlsrv_fetch($result, SQLSRV_SCROLL_NEXT);  
$v2 = sqlsrv_get_field( $result, 0);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch($result, SQLSRV_SCROLL_NEXT);  
$v3 = sqlsrv_get_field( $result, 0);
```

How do I get the array from the second column into a variable though?

Comment: I think the second parameter of sqlsrv_get_field will point to the index of the column. In this case: `$c2 = sqlsrv_get_field($result,1);`

Comment: I thought the same and I think it does but because it's an array stored as a string, it simply outputs "Resource id #13".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my question in my comment above!  DOH!

It's an array, not a string so using the original code, I just needed to change it to;

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch($result, SQLSRV_SCROLL_FIRST);  
$v1 = sqlsrv_get_field( $result, 0);
$v2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, 1);  
$row = sqlsrv_fetch($result, SQLSRV_SCROLL_NEXT);  
$v3 = sqlsrv_get_field( $result, 0);
$v4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, 1);  
$row = sqlsrv_fetch($result, SQLSRV_SCROLL_NEXT);  
$v5 = sqlsrv_get_field( $result, 0);
$v6 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, 1);
```

The final version auto increments the variable name in the while loop;

```
$i=0;    
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
  ${'name'.$i} = $row[0]."<br />";     
  ${'value'.$i} = $row[1]."<br />";
  $i++;
}
```

$name1, $value1, $name2, $value2 and so on until the loop ends.